# How to write simultaneously Textbox values in another Textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I Want to Write simultaneously Textbox values in another Textbox like in Your Website.

Javascript

```
window.update = function() {
    var one = document.getElementById('one'),
    two = document.getElementById('two');
    two.value = parseInt(one.value) * 2;
}​
```

Html

```
<input id="one" type="text" onchange="update();" />
<input id="two" type="text" />​
```

Comment: Kindly put some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say `$('#textbox1').on('keyup', function (e) { $('#textbox2').val($('#textbox1').val()) });` I'm pretty sure that is the solution

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

                window.update = function() {
                    var one = document.getElementById('one'),
                        two = document.getElementById('two');    

                    two.value = parseInt(one.value) * 2;
                }​
                   </script>

                <!-- in your HTML: -->
               
                    </


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       
         <input id="one" type="text" onchange="update();" />
                <input id="two" type="text" />​

    </div>

Comment: put that code in your question... and make sure you have it formatted as code..

Comment: i mean to say that when i fill some values in textbox then auto fill in second textbox without pageload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function update() {
            var one = document.getElementById('one');
            var two = document.getElementById('two');
            two.value = parseInt(one.value) * 2;
        } 
    </script>
 </head> 
 <body> 
     <input id="one" type="text" onchange="update()" /> <br />
     <input id="two" type="text" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

[JsFiddleExample](http://jsfiddle.net/kt0g1ssL/1/)